# 500 Internal Service Error

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, internal

I have a SOAP server. When the connection was through PHP the result is correct, but when I use a tool like SoapUI get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Bad Request</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is the response of the head:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Service Error Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 22:07:42
>   GMT

If I comment the following line in the file server no longer get the 500 internal:

```
$server->handle();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built in PHP Soapclient to make the call, and it works, then you do `$soapclient->__getLastRequest()` and compare the XML with the request generated by SoapUI.  This should help you troubleshoot the SoapUI request.